# PHP RSS Parser (Magpie) Deep elements

Tags: php

Im using Magpie RSS Parser (http://magpierss.sourceforge.net)

Here is the vardump:

```
array(11) {
  ["dc"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["creator"]=>
    string(9) "Microsoft"
  }
  ["title"]=>
  string(16) "The Type We Want"
  ["description"]=>
  string(245) "After a slow evolution, the landscape for custom type on the web has been changing quickly. This session will cover the history of embedding fonts, diving into the options available to us today and finally taking a look at the hurdles before us."
  ["link"]=>
  string(44) "http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/DS15"
  ["guid"]=>
  string(44) "http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/DS15"
  ["pubdate"]=>
  string(29) "Tue, 02 Mar 2010 09:51:34 GMT"
  ["category"]=>
  string(2) "UX"
  ["evnet"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["starttime"]=>
    string(29) "Wed, 17 Mar 2010 09:00:00 GMT"
    ["endtime"]=>
    string(29) "Wed, 17 Mar 2010 10:00:00 GMT"
    ["location"]=>
    string(9) "Lagoon GH"
    ["speaker"]=>
    string(17) "
                "
    ["speaker_displayname"]=>
    string(14) "Jonathan Snook"
    ["speaker_moreinfo"]=>
    string(48) "http://live.visitmix.com/Speakers/Jonathan-Snook"
  }
  ["speaker"]=>
  string(30) "

            "
  ["summary"]=>
  string(245) "After a slow evolution, the landscape for custom type on the web has been changing quickly. This session will cover the history of embedding fonts, diving into the options available to us today and finally taking a look at the hurdles before us."
  ["date_timestamp"]=>
  int(1267523494)
}
```

I want to echo these elements:

```
["evnet"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["starttime"]=>
        string(29) "Wed, 17 Mar 2010 09:00:00 GMT"
        ["endtime"]=>
        string(29) "Wed, 17 Mar 2010 10:00:00 GMT"
        ["location"]=>
        string(9) "Lagoon GH"
        ["speaker"]=>
        string(17) "
                    "
        ["speaker_displayname"]=>
        string(14) "Jonathan Snook"
        ["speaker_moreinfo"]=>
        string(48) "http://live.visitmix.com/Speakers/Jonathan-Snook"
      }
```

I already have:

```
<?php require_once('magpie/rss_fetch.inc');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://live.visitmix.com/Sessions/RSS');

foreach ($rss->items as $item) {
        $href = $item['link'];
        $title = $item['title'];
        $desc = $item['description'];
        $cat = $item['category'];
        echo '<p><a href="$href">'.$title.'</a><br>';
        if($desc) echo $desc;

}



?>
```

Can anyone help me echo those items which appear to be in an array?

For instance             `$cat = $item['starttime'];` doesnt work.

Comment: Elaborate, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I dont know how to get the 'evnet' elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( $rss->items as $item ) {
   // ...
   $event = $item['evnet'];
   $start = $event['starttime'];
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$cat = $item['evnet']['starttime'];